# Trouble with installing rbenv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, homebrew

I'm having trouble installing rbenv-
Whenever I run `brew install rbenv`
I get the error

````
Warning: No available formula with the name "rbenv".
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.```
````

Comment: Have you done `brew update` recently? It's often helpful to `brew search rbenv`. Also, what's your `brew --version`?

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue with `rm -rf "/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core" && brew tap homebrew/core)`. Here is the reference [link](https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/2769#discussioncomment-1956665)